# Excel VBA: protecting my worksheets slows down my vba code significantly

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I am very new to VBA and have basically taught myself while building my current Excel 'contract'.  My goal is have a list of contract options which are shown or  hidden depending on their representative check boxes.  There are 12 total options with ranges that I show/remove across 4 worksheets.

In terms of organization, I have utilized modules based on each action.  I also named all my ranges

Prior to me protecting my worksheet, when I select a checkbox, all 4 ranges across all 4 worksheets immediately show.  When I unselect, they immediately clear their contents and hide.  Yay!

Once I protect my worksheet, however, things either slow down to a crawl or I get an error.  In my ProtectWorksheet module below, the commented out lines work, but from reading other stack overflow articles it seens better to use the code I have.  Unprotected, it works great.  Protected I get the "Error 1004': Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class".  If I instead use my commented out code while protected, it works but is super slow.

Technically I can get everything to work...but from a user interface stance it's terrible.

Below is the 1st contract option I have been testing.  Please and thank you for any and all help!

***under the Excel Objects - sheet2(Data Input)***

```
Private Sub chkDomesticHotWater_Click()

ProtectOFF

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  If chkDomesticHotWater = True Then
    AddDomesticHotWater
  Else
    'Remove the lines, clear the data, and move the mouse to the top
    RemoveDomesticHotWater
    ClearDomesticHotWater
    Range("A1").Select
  End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ProtectON

End Sub
```

***under the Module: Checkboxes***

```
 Sub AddDomesticHotWater()
    [DataInput_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    [Contract_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    [Invoice_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    [ExpectedCost_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = False
 End Sub
 Sub RemoveDomesticHotWater()
    [DataInput_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    [Contract_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    [Invoice_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    [ExpectedCost_DomesticHotWater].EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End Sub
```

***Under the Module ClearData***

```
Sub ClearDomesticHotWater()
  Range("DataInput_DomesticHotWater").Select
  For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218) Then
      cell.ClearContents
    End If
  Next
  Range("DomesticHotWaterStart").Select
End Sub
```

***under the Module ProtectWorksheet***

```
Sub ProtectON()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

pwd = "123" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
  ws.Protect Password:=pwd, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next ws

'Worksheets("Data Input").Protect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Contract").Protect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Invoice").Protect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Expected Cost").Protect Password:="123"
End Sub

Sub ProtectOFF()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

pwd = "123" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
  ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws
'Worksheets("Data Input").Unprotect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Contract").Unprotect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Invoice").Unprotect Password:="123"
'Worksheets("Expected Cost").Unprotect Password:="123"
End Sub
```

***EDIT***
I was able to speed it up just a tiny bit by updating my Protect On/Off code below, but it's still a 3-5 second delay when I click on my check boxes:

```
Sub ProtectON()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Data Input", "Contract", "Invoice", "Expected Cost"))
    For Each ws In WSArray
         ws.Protect Password:="123"
    Next
End Sub

Sub ProtectOFF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Data Input", "Contract", "Invoice", "Expected Cost"))
    For Each ws In WSArray
     ws.Unprotect Password:="123"
    Next
End Sub
```

***EDIT - SOLUTION?***
So I don't think this is best practice, nor have I really 'solved' my delay, but I found a workaround.  I eliminated the delay when clicking my check boxes by turning on protection yet allowing row formatting.  Technically my sheet is no longer 100% protected from user tinkering, but I think that risk is worth removing such an annoying wait time after clicking.

```
Sub ProtectON()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Data Input", "Contract", "Invoice", "Expected Cost"))
For Each ws In WSArray
     ws.Protect Password:="123", AllowFormattingRows:=True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't hide rows when the sheet is protected, unless you explicitly set that parameter when protecting to allow you to do so.

Comment: I turn off the protection at the beginning of my checkbox-has-been-clicked code.  How would I set the parameter to all me to do so even if protected?  Would I need to allow the formatting of rows?  Thanks!

Comment: I was able to speed it up just a tiny bit by updating my Protect On/Off code below, but it's still a 3-5 second delay when I click on my check boxes or other buttons:

    Sub ProtectON()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Data Input", "Contract", "Invoice",     "Expected Cost"))
        For Each ws In WSArray
             ws.Protect Password:="123"
        Next
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It should not be that slow, although I really have no clue how fast is your PC and how big is the data. However, here is something you can make better:

```
Sub ClearDomesticHotWater()

    For Each cell In [DataInput_DomesticHotWater]
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218) Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

and remove all selects, they are slowing you down. Go around them like this:
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: The size of my data is the above multiplied by 12 sections, excluding the ProtectWorksheet module.  I also have a ton of formulas within the cells I am showing/hiding.

Thank you for the removing selects article, I am reading through that now